# Nested React + Meteor component not receiving props on page load

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor, react-router

I have a nested React component called Profile. On a complete page refresh all of the data is loaded correctly, but when I click a link to take me to a different page such as Settings, and then navigate back to Profile, no data loads. I noticed that on refresh, componentWillReceiveProps fires my console.log, but when I use the link it doesn't fire. I wonder if this is due to my createContainer not unmounting correctly?

[image: Profile receives props on full refresh and loads correctly.]
[image: I navigate to settings and everything works correctly.]
[image: I navigate back to profile and nothing loads, componentWillReceiveProps is not fired]

Pic 1: Profile receives props on full refresh and loads correctly.
Pic 2: I navigate to settings and everything works correctly.
Pic 3: I navigate back to profile and nothing loads, componentWillReceiveProps is not fired

These components are nested routes using react router. But I'm confused how settings works fine with no distinct code differences.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

ProfileContainer.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { createContainer } from 'meteor/react-meteor-data';
import introJs from 'intro.js';
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router';
import '../../../../../node_modules/intro.js/introjs.css';

// Custom
import ProfileForm from './ProfileForm';
import { countryList, statesList, industryList, incomesList, monthsList, educationsList, ofAgeCheck } from '../../../../modules/helpers.js';
import { upsertUserProfile } from '../../../../../imports/api/methods/profile/settingsMethods';
import { changeIntroTour } from '../../../../api/methods/user/userMethods';

// Collections
import { UserProfile } from '../../../../api/collections/profile/userProfileCollection';
import { IntroTour } from '../../../../api/collections/user/introTourCollection';

const expertiseOptions = [];
const dayOptions = [];
const yearOptions = [];

const profileIntro = {
  text: 'Tell us a little about yourself.',
};
const tourObj = {
  userId: Meteor.userId(),
  page: 'profile',
};
class ProfileFormContainer extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    const NA = 'N/A';
    this.state = {
      firstView: NA,
      birthmonth: NA,
      birthday: NA,
      birthyear: NA,
      sex: NA,
      expertise: '',
      country: '',
      state: '',
      industry: '',
      income: '',
      education: '',
      showTour: false,
      tourRunning: false,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.loadExpertiseOptions();
    this.loadBirthdateOptions();
    this.handleChange = this
      .handleChange
      .bind(this);
    this.upsertToDB = this
      .upsertToDB
      .bind(this);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    introJs.introJs().exit();
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    console.log(nextProps);
    this.existingSettings(nextProps);
    if (nextProps.intro.length > 0) {
      this.setState({
        showTour: nextProps.intro[0].profileTour,
      }, () => {
        if (!this.state.tourRunning) {
          this.runTour();
        }
      });
    }
  }

  runTour() {
    if (this.state.showTour === true) {
      this.setState({
        tourRunning: true,
      });
      introJs.introJs().setOption('doneLabel', 'Next').start().oncomplete(() => {
        changeIntroTour.call(tourObj);
        browserHistory.push('/user/settings');
      })
        .onexit(() => {
          changeIntroTour.call(tourObj);
        });
    }
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value,
    });
  }

  existingSettings(data) {
    const user = data.profile[0];
    this.setState({
      birthmonth: user.birthmonth,
      birthday: user.birthday,
      birthyear: user.birthyear,
      sex: user.sex,
      expertise: user.expertise,
      country: user.country,
      state: user.state,
      industry: user.industry,
      income: user.income,
      education: user.education,
    });
  }

  loadExpertiseOptions() {
    for (let i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
      expertiseOptions.push(
        <option key={ i } value={ i }>
          { i }
        </option>
      );
    }
  }


  loadBirthdateOptions() {
    this.loadDayOptions();
    this.loadYearOptions();
  }

  loadDayOptions() {
    dayOptions.push(
      <option key={ ' ' } value={ ' ' }>
      </option>
    );
    for (let i = 1; i <= 31; i++) {
      dayOptions.push(
        <option key={ i } value={ i }>
          { i }
        </option>
      );
    }
  }

  loadYearOptions() {
    yearOptions.push(
      <option key={ ' ' } value={ ' ' }>
      </option>
    );
    for (let i = new Date().getFullYear(); i >= 1900; i--) {
      yearOptions.push(
        <option key={ i } value={ i }>
          { i }
        </option>
      );
    }
  }

  upsertToDB() {
    if (ofAgeCheck(13, this.state.birthmonth, this.state.birthday, this.state.birthyear)) {
      Bert.alert('If you are under 13 years of age, then please do not use the service.', 'danger');
    } else if (this.state.birthday === 'N/A' || this.state.birthmonth === 'N/A' || this.state.birthyear === 'N/A' || this.state.sex === 'N/A') {
      Bert.alert('Please complete all required fields.', 'danger');
    } else {
      const birthdateFormatted = `${this.state.birthmonth}-${this.state.birthday}-${this.state.birthyear}`;
      const settingsObj = {
        userId: Meteor.userId(),
        birthmonth: this.state.birthmonth,
        birthday: this.state.birthday,
        birthyear: this.state.birthyear,
        birthdate: birthdateFormatted,
        sex: this.state.sex,
        expertise: this.state.expertise,
        country: this.state.country,
        state: this.state.state,
        industry: this.state.industry,
        income: this.state.income,
        education: this.state.education,
      };

      upsertUserProfile.call(settingsObj, (error, response) => {
        if (error) {
          Bert.alert('Save unsuccessful.', 'danger');
        } else {
          if (this.state.tourRunning) {
            changeIntroTour.call(tourObj);

            browserHistory.push('/user/settings');
          }
          Bert.alert('Save successful!', 'success');
        }
      });
    }
  }

  render() {
    const countries = countryList();
    const states = statesList();
    const industries = industryList();
    const incomes = incomesList();
    const months = monthsList();
    const educations = educationsList();

    if (!this.props.ready) {
      return (
        <div>Loading user profile...</div>
        );
    }

    return (
      <ProfileForm {...this.state} months={ months } dayOptions={ dayOptions } yearOptions={ yearOptions } expertise={ expertiseOptions } countries={ countries }
        states={ states } industries={ industries } incomes={ incomes } educations={ educations } handleChange={ this.handleChange } upsertToDB={ this.upsertToDB }
        profileIntro={ profileIntro } />
      );
  }
}

ProfileFormContainer.PropTypes = {
  ready: React.PropTypes.bool,
  profile: React.PropTypes.array,
};

export default createContainer(() => {
  const userProfile = Meteor.subscribe('userProfile', Meteor.userId());
  const introTour = Meteor.subscribe('introTour', Meteor.userId());
  return {
    ready: userProfile.ready(),
    profile: UserProfile.find({}).fetch(),
    intro: IntroTour.find({}).fetch(),
  };
}, ProfileFormContainer);
```

Here is the react router code

```
 <Router history={browserHistory}>
      <Route name="Home" path="/" component={Main} >
        <IndexRoute component={Index} onEnter={authenticate} />
        <Route name="Asset Allocation" path="/asset-allocation" 
component={AssetAllocation} />
        <Route name="Recover Password" path="/recover-password" 
component={RecoverPassword} />
        <Route name="Reset Password" path="/reset-password/:token" 
component={ResetPassword} />
        <Route name="User" path="/user" component={Profile}>
          <Route name="About" path="/user/home" component={User} />
          <Route name="Profile" path="/user/profile" component=
{ProfileForm} />
          <Route name="Settings" path="/user/settings" component=
{SettingsForm} />
        </Route>
      </Route>
      <Route component={Blank}>
        <Route name="Login" path="/login" component={Login} onEnter=
{loggedIn} />
        <Route name="Signup" path="/signup" component={Signup} onEnter=
{loggedIn} />
        <Route name="Not Found" path="*" component={NotFound} onEnter=
{notFound} />
      </Route>
    </Router>,
```

Comment: Try this. Add a componentWillUnmount method to your ProfileContainer and put a `console.log("unmounting");` line in it. Then check if it unmounts when you navigate away from it.

Comment: @KyleRichardson all components are unmounting when navigating away from it.

Comment: Try adding unique keys to youtr generated arrays.

Comment: @KyleRichardson I think it has to do with how I have the routes nested. When I navigate to another component that isn't nested along the profile route and then switch back to the profile route everything works correctly. I added my react router code in the main post.

Comment: @OP What version of `react-router` are you using?

Comment: @KyleRichardson react-router": "^3.0.0"

Answer (score 0):

This is from the [react-router/v3/docs](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v3/docs/guides/RouteConfiguration.md#route-configuration).

```
<Router>
  <Route path="/" component={App}>
    <Route path="about" component={About} />
    <Route path="inbox" component={Inbox}>
      <Route path="messages/:id" component={Message} />
    </Route>
  </Route>
</Router>
```

Notice how the nested routes do not have a leading or trailing slash. Follow that convention and I think you'll fix your problem.

EDIT: In response to your comment.

This is from the React [componentWillReceiveProps](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops) documentation:

> React doesn't call componentWillReceiveProps with initial props during mounting. It only calls this method if some of component's props may update. Calling this.setState generally doesn't trigger componentWillReceiveProps.

Try moving your data retrieving function to the `componentDidMount` lifecycle hook.

Comment: I've updated all routes. The issue is that when I navigate back to the page componentWillReceiveProps doesn't get fired which then causes my function that loads the data not to be called. The props are being passed in through my createContainer/meteor subscriptions. Would that mean the subscriptions are not successfully unsubscribing when the component is unmounted?